# Busca no Elastic passar uma lista e retornar todos matchs

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Preciso realizar uma busca no elastic search, porém estou tendo dificuldades

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery()
            .must(matchQuery(CLIENT_ID, clientId));

fieldValues
      .forEach(fieldValue -> query.must(boolQuery().should(matchQuery(FIELD_NAME, fieldValue))));
```

*fieldValues* é uma lista de strings. E eu gostaria de ter o resultado do match de todos os valores que tenho na lista com o campo FIELD_NAME. Porém da forma que implementei, ele resulta 0 sempre, pois pelo que entendi, ele tenta dar match com o primeiro valor E todos os restantes. Gostaria de uma operação OR e não AND.

Comment: Nunca usei essa api de java para ElasticSearch, mas aparentemente o problema esta sendo o uso do MUST. Acredito que você não precise do Must que esta escrito dentro do foreach, tente chamar direto o query.should(matchQuery(FIELD_NAME, fieldValue)).

Comment: Ae cara. Cara, valeu pela resposta, mas como resultado vem tudo. Imagino que seja pela query de cima. Parece que é pego tudo que pertence ao id do cliente. Eai na hora de dar o match, ele não desconsidera os que não derem match. Se ajudar, posso mostrar a query resultante.

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar em uma lista você pode usar filtros e deve usar "terms" passando o campo e a lista de valores.

```
GET /empresas/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"terms": {"CLIENT_ID": ["3085","2062","2002","2003"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```